# Multiple TcpClients with same local port in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, p2p

I'm working on a peer-to-peer file sharing application that can be used to transfer files without having a central server.

It works like a charm when it comes to one-to-one file transfer, however I originally planned it in a way, that the sender can send files to multiple clients.

The app uses **TCP Hole Punching** so port forwarding is not necessary. The problem is, that in order to make TCP hole punch work, I need to specify a local port for each TCPClient. Thus, I need to bind the sockets.

```
TCPClient client = new TCPClient(port);
```

The problem is, that when it comes to the creation of the a new client (after establishing a connection), I'll get the error which states I am unable to bind a new socket.

As far as I'm concerned, a socket is identified as a **Local Port with Local IP AND Remote Port with Remote IP AND Protocol**. Thus, if two sockets differ in one of these 4, they can be handled as separate connections.
Yet, I still get exception.[image]

How can I do **TCP Hole Punching** with multiple clients? According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_hole_punching) wikipedia page, it should work, if the sender does not bind the sockets.

[image]

Here is the code for my `Connect()` method in my custom `NetClient` class. (It contains a `TcpClient` and represents a connection with a remote endpoint.)

```
private async Task<bool> Connect(string _ip)
{
    IPEndPoint _endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
    tcpClient = new TcpClient(_endPoint);

    int tick = timeOut;
    while (tick >= 0)
    {
       try { await tcpClient?.ConnectAsync(_ip, port); }
       catch { }

       if (tcpClient.Connected) return true;

       tick--;
       await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Still, no luck. Can someone help please?

Comment: It's better to show some code which reproduces the problem

Comment: Binding the sockets is irrelevant. You need to know the port the NAT router uses for the connection, not the port your computer uses for the connection.

Comment: But port prediction is needed to make hole punch work. One way to make port prediction is to set the internal port to the same as the external. So I chose this method, avoiding the requirement of a STUN server (at least I think it is called STUN).

Comment: @Evk edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've found a solution! For those who might stuck with the same problem, apparently there is an option to tell the TCP socket that the local endpoint **can be reused**.

Depending on the OS and the TCP implementation, you can add the option `SO_REUSEADDRESS` and `SO_REUSEPORT` for the socket. This will make the socket ignore endpoint duplication. (As far as I'm concerned it only works on the local endpoint.)

Head over [this](https://bford.info/pub/net/p2pnat/index.html#SECTION00040000000000000000) website for further information on the topic, it is a very good read.

Now for that, you will need to set these properties **BEFORE** binding the socket. So you will need to call `socket.Bind()` separately from the TcpClient constructor.

Use `TcpClient.Client` to access the socket of the tcpClient.

Proper way of creating a TcpClient with reusable local endpoint:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseUnicastPort, true);
client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);

client.Client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port));
```

After these steps, you should not experience any problem with socket binding. Hope that helped!